# .NET 5 IValidateOptions does not validate automatically

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-5

Based on the microsoft documentation we can define validators for specific configurations using IValidateOptions.

Currently following the documentation is not validating automatically. Has anyone experienced this problem? Possible solutions?

I've tried documentation code directly:

Config class:

```
    public class MyConfigOptions
{
    public const string MyConfig = "MyConfig";

    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public int Key2 { get; set; }
    public int Key3 { get; set; }
}
```

Validation:

```
 public class MyConfigValidation : IValidateOptions<MyConfigOptions>
{
    public MyConfigOptions _config { get; private set; }

    public MyConfigValidation(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config.GetSection(MyConfigOptions.MyConfig)
            .Get<MyConfigOptions>();
    }

    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyConfigOptions options)
    {
        string vor = null;
        var rx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$");
        var match = rx.Match(options.Key1);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
        {
            vor = $"{options.Key1} doesn't match RegEx \n";
        }

        if (options.Key2 < 0 || options.Key2 > 1000)
        {
            vor = $"{options.Key2} doesn't match Range 0 - 1000 \n";
        }

        if (_config.Key2 != default)
        {
            if (_config.Key3 <= _config.Key2)
            {
                vor += "Key3 must be > than Key2.";
            }
        }

        if (vor != null)
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(vor);
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

In startup:

```
 services.Configure<MyConfigOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(
                                   MyConfigOptions.MyConfig));
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IValidateOptions
                              <MyConfigOptions>, MyConfigValidation>());
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Validate method of MyConfigValidation is never accesed. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://newbedev.com/how-to-validate-configuration-settings-using-ivalidateoptions-in-asp-net-core-2-2

Comment: Thanks @AliReza. I just read that document yesterday. Although using GetService I have not been able to force the validation if I have hit the key of the problem for something that it comments right there. Validation does not occur until the service is injected.

I will self answer the question in case it will serve someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer in case anyone has this problem in the future. I was trying to force validation during Startup but it doesn't happen **until we inject it into some component.**
In my case I prefer to use Microsoft convention using IOptionsMonitor directly instead of declare a singleton for the specific configuration.
So we can do:

```
public IndexModel (ILogger <IndexModel> logger, IOptionsMonitor <MyConfigOptions > settings)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _settings = settings.CurrentValue;
        }
```

And at that time it will be validated.

**Validation also occurs if we instantiate the service from the service provider.**